# Using a common preamble.sty for all sharelatex projects

Tags: sharelatex

I have several projects on sharelatex. Is there a way to use a common preamble.sty for all of them?

Presently, I have different preambles for different documents, but no two preambles are the same -- I get lazy and don't keep them all consistent (that would be a hassle really).

Comment: Let's say you want to download a project to sent it to a friend... The download has to download all your used code to work everywhere that latex is installed... So it is better just to copy this file to every project (to make it independent from other projects)

Comment: The preamble is one file. Surely its additional download doesn't add much strain?

Comment: I found out that sharelatex allows sinc with dropbox... So, if you are a dropbox user, you could try to use it and add a symbolic link file instead of your one .sty to every folder that need it... May be it works this way and you don't have to copy it in every change. I know this probably is not what you want but is a possible solution (if works) to avoid multiple files and multiple changes to your original `sty` file.